# Semiring construction from a monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid, semiring

Reading throug the paper [Definable sets up to definable bijections in Presburger groups](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.02997.pdf) by Raf Cluckers and Immanuel Halupczok, I have come across a construction (Definition 2.2.1) that builds a commutative semiring out of a commutative monoid $M$.

At first, I thought it was talking about the set of all maps $M\to \mathbb{N}$ with finite support where + is given by addition of maps and $\times$ is the Cauchy product
$$
(f \times g)(z) = \sum_{a+b = z} f(a)g(b) \cdot \textbf{1}_z 
$$
where $\textbf{1}_z$ is the map sending $z \mapsto 1$ and every other element to $0$. The construction continues by identifying the elements
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\textbf{1}_a + \textbf{1}_b = \textbf{1}_{a+b}\\
\textbf{1}_0 = 0\\
\textbf{1}_g = 1\\
\end{array}
$$
where $0$ and $1$ are the neutral elements of the resulting semiring and $g$ is a preselected element of $M$.

The authors provide an example (after Theorem 2.3.4) of such a construction applied to the monoid $\mathbb{N}_\infty$.

When I follow this construction, I get that the elements of the resulting semiring are equivalence classes represented by
$$
\mathbb{N}_+ \cup \{\infty\}
$$
while they assert that they should be given by
$$
\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty, \infty^2, \infty^3,\dots\}
$$

Is there another construction of a semiring where after doing the identification this is the resulting semiring?

They name the construction as reduced symmetric algebra, but reading about symmetric algebras I can't figure out what is the mathematical object they are constructing.

Comment: What I read here is "I came across a construction... at first I thought it was this other construction..." so now I am confused if you are describing the other construction or the one you are confused about. Please clarify.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_algebraic_structures#Types_of_algebraic_structures ?

Comment: @rschwieb The construction I provide was my first guess, but it is not the correct one. I am looking for a different construction that provides the semiring with elements $\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty,\infty^2,\dots\}$ when applied to the example given.

Comment: @MartinAzpillaga It is silly to ask us to reverse-engineer a construction to explain something you read in a paper which you haven't even cited for us. Someone may be able to do it, but otherwise you are not giving the rest of us much to go on.

Comment: @MartinAzpillaga You're saying that you're familiar with semigroup rings and you think that is not the construction implied?

Comment: @MartinAzpillaga Put that in the body of the question, not the comments...

Comment: @MartinAzpillaga I am looking at Definition 2.3.1 right now, and I cannot see any resemblance to your question. [This is what I'm looking at](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.02997.pdf)

Comment: @rschwieb That one is the correct paper. There is a chance that I am totally wrong. My question is: What is this reduced symmetric algebra they define there?

Comment: @rschwieb http://latexsearch.com/ may help if you can mimic what would be written in the paper.

Comment: @MartinAzpillaga OK, I've got it. You are apparently looking at Definition **2.2.1**. So... if you could be a little more careful that would be nice.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, the question has been accordingly updated.

Comment: @MartinAzpillaga In a case like this, it's also in your best interest to provide the description. Making readers chase through links and documents to figure out what you're talking about is going to deter a lot of them. The entire description is not even as long as what you already wrote.

Comment: It looks like a straightforward quotient of a free semiring (or semigroup-semiring, if you prefer), but the weird part is that the semigroup operation is being blended with the $+$ operation of the semiring. (for normal semigroup rings, of course, the semigroup operation becomes the $\cdot$ operation of the semigroupring.) That's very strange to me, and I don't recognize it, or even know if it's a real thing. But it probably is a thing. Math is a big ocean.

Comment: @rschwieb At least is not only me who finds it strange. Seems like you are close to understand it though. It would be great if you could add a proper answer explaining the construction in more detail.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic  is my first thought that you might be missing it's not necessarily peano arithmetic multiplication doesn't happen in presburger based on that article.

Comment: @MartinAzpillaga If I understood it, I would post an answer. Honestly I'm a bit skeptical about it. I just don't see what's happening to the original semigroup operation. My advice would simply to be to email the authors directly. I found [one author](http://rcluckers.perso.math.cnrs.fr/) right away, and I didn't search for the other one.

Comment: "Later on, the authors provide the example ..." Be more precise and give us the precise page and line.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin A reference to the example has been added to the question. It is just after Theorem 2.3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the construction as given in the article is correct. First of all, given a set $G$, the free commutative semiring over $G$ is the semiring of commutative polynomials $\mathbb{N}[(X_g)_{g \in G}]$.

Let $G$ be a commutative monoid and let $s: (\mathbb{N},+) \to G$ be a monoid homomorphism. Now, the semiring defined in the article is the quotient $SG$ of $\mathbb{N}[(X_g)_{g \in G}]$ by the relations $X_0 = 0$, $X_{s(1)} = 1$ and $X_g + X_h = X_{g+h}$.

Suppose first that $G = \mathbb{N}$. Then, one gets by induction the relations $X_n = n$ for all $n$ and hence $SG = \mathbb{N}$. If now $G = \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$, one gets the further relations $X_n + X_\infty = X_\infty$, whence $n + X_\infty = X_\infty$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $X_\infty + X_\infty = X_\infty$. It follows that in this case, $SG$ is the quotient of $\mathbb{N}[X_\infty]$ by the relations $n + X_\infty = X_\infty$ and $X_\infty + X_\infty = X_\infty$. It follows that $kX_\infty = X_\infty$ for all $k > 0$. Moreover
$X_\infty^2 = X_\infty(1 + X_\infty) = X_\infty  + X_\infty^2$.

Consider now a polynomial $c_{i_1}X_\infty^{i_1} + \ldots + c_{i_n}X_\infty^{i_n}$, with nonzero coefficients and $i_1 < \dotsm < i_n$. Then
$$c_{i_1}X_\infty^{i_1} + \dotsm + c_{i_n}X_\infty^{i_n} = X_\infty^{i_1} + \dotsm + X_\infty^{i_n} = X_\infty^{i_n}$$
and thus $SG = \mathbb{N} \cup \{X_\infty^k \mid k \in \mathbb{N}\}$.